# Pegar o valor de uma <td> listada (JSP)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Eae galera.

Estou fazendo um sistema para a faculdade, gostaria de saber se vocês do fórum conseguiriam resolver um problema que estou passando.

Minha tela de vender precisa pegar o valor de preço unitário que está em uma tabela. O usuário consegue colocar o serviço que ele quiser que está em uma box, ao clicar no serviço preciso puxar automaticamente o preço unitário. O que lista meu box é um c:forEach.

```
<section id="principal">
    <form name="formVendas" method="get" action= "" method="get">
        <h1>Vender</h1>
        <p><label>Nome do serviço:<select id="camposervico" class="tempNome" name="servico">
                    <c:forEach var="servico" items="${dao.listar()}">
                        <option name="${servico.nomeServico}">${servico.nomeServico}</option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select></label>
            <label>Quantidade:<input type="text" class="tempQuantidade" name="quantidade"></label>
            <label>Preço Unitário:<input type="text" class="tempPrecoUnitario" name="precounitario" ></label>
            <label>Valor total:<input type="text" class="tempInsert"  value="" name="valortotal"></label>
            <button type="button" id="tempBtn" onclick="calcularTotal()">Adicionar</button>
        </p>

        <table width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Serviço</th>
                    <th>Preço Unitário</th>
                    <th>Quantidade</th>
                    <th>Valor Total</th>
                    <th>Remover</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>



    </form>
</section>
<script src="./resources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Quer pegar o valor quando o usuário bota no input ou quando ele já clica em adicionar e aparece na tabela ali embaixo?

Comment: quando ele escolhe no select o serviço puxar o preço unitário do serviço que escolheu e colocar no input